# Using select(name).options in Angular E2E test

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multi-value selector, which I am trying to write an E2E test for. Using `select(name).option` works fine, but when I try to use `select(name).options` to select multiple values it doesn't work.

I tried to put together some code together to demonstrate, but can't get it working.

HTML:

```html
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>End2end Test Runner</title>
      <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.1/angular-scenario-1.0.1.js"
      ng-autotest>
      </script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="MyApp">
      <div ng-controller="MyAppCtrl">
         {{model.exampleValue}}
         <select id="a_selector"                 
            ng-model="model.selectedItems"
            ng-options="item.name for item in model.items"
            multiple="multiple">
         </select>
      </div>
   </body>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource'])
app.controller('MyAppCtrl', function($scope) {         
     $scope.model = {};
     $scope.model.exampleValue="an example value";
     $scope.model.items = [{"name": "Product1"}, {"name": "Product2"}];
});
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider, $scope) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {controller:MyAppCtrl});
}]);
describe('my app', function() { 
  it('should display the home page', function() {                  
    browser().navigateTo('/');
    // this should work (when I can fix this code!)
    select("model.selectedItems").option("Product1");
    expect(element("#a_selector option:selected").count()).toEqual(1)

    // this doesn't, nothing is selected
    select("model.selectedItems").options("Product1", "Product2");
    expect(element("#a_selector option:selected").count()).toEqual(2)
  });
});
```

The line

```
select("model.selectedItems").option("Product1");
```

fails with error message:

```
Selector select[ng\:model="model.selectedItems"] did not match any elements.
```

I'd appreciate it if someone can (1) help me identify why the above code isn't working at all, and (2) help me understand why `select(name).options` isn't working. (I know there are other techniques I could use to achieve the same thing, but the real `select` in the production code also has an `ng-change` attribute which does not fire when I try the workarounds).

Thanks,

Graeme Ludwig.

Answer (score 1):

I am still trying to figure out why the `select(name).option()` is not working but I could get your example working by the following modifications:

1. Include angular.js before angular-scenario.js
2. Take out ngResource dependency - you don't need it here
3. Put `<span>{{model.selectedItems}}</span>` after your `<select>` tag to see what you have chosen.

I will update once I figure out the second part.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `select("model.selectedItems").option("Product1");` be `select("#a_selector").option("Product1");` instead?